# div with position absolute doesn't overlap div with position relative

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="absolute">
</div>
<div class="relative">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.absolute {
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv96zy10/

How to do div with position over div using position relative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index` to control the stack order.

Give the div you want on top a higher `z-index` number.

Comment: Ye, thank you so much! I had already guessed. I will be accept your answer after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify what @Quentin mentioned above your css should look like

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
.relative {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #eee;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 0; 
}
.absolute {
   background-color: #000;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}`
```

when positioning elements over each other, the lowest z-index is going to be behind everything that has a higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.absolute {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv96zy10/2/)